# Boston Fern leaves turning black

Tags: houseplants, leaves, ferns

I bought this from a nursery a few days ago, and noticed the leaves are turning black. Is this normal?

[image: Fern close-up]
[image: Underside of fern]

- Water: Last watered two days ago, top of soil feels damp but not dripping
- Light: It's on a shaded area, maybe 4 hrs direct sunlight + 8 hrs indirect
- Bugs: No sign of any
- Soil: Did not change

This is my first time with a fern and I'm worried. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not normal, no, but you say it  receives about  4 hours sunlight a day? These plants do not like direct sun, they prefer bright, diffuse light, so a position near a bright daylight but not sunny window would be best. Sun exposure might explain the problem, but once you relocate it, if it gets worse, it may have another issue. Care of indoor Boston fern details here https://thegardeningcook.com/care-of-boston-fern/

Comment: Yeah you're right, I think it might have been "sunburn" (if there is such a thing in plants). It got 4 hours direct and about 8 hours of cloudy sun. Thank you for the advice, I've moved it :)